How to distinguish interaction from mediation?
I’ve been reflecting on an analysis I performed as part of a randomized clinical trial. The study includes three repeated measurements, where each individual is followed up three times. However, my question is not about the longitudinal aspects of the model but rather about the theoretical and statistical concepts involved.
Specifically, I analyzed a biomarker of interest, which might be influenced by the participants’ weight. In my model, I tested an interaction between sex and weight, alongside other covariates. Here is the model setup:
#sexo_s1:sex
#i_huleptin: biomarker of interest
# peso1:weight
#grupo_int_v00: group of the clinical trial

lme_leptin <- lme(i_huleptin ~ sexo_s1*peso1 + edad_s1 + poly(time, 2)*grupo_int_v00 + p17_total, 
           random = ~ poly(time, 2)|paciente, control=lmeControl(opt="optim"),
           data = dat_longer, subset = !is.na(i_huleptin))
summary(lme_leptin)
res_lme_leptin <- as.data.frame(coef(summary(lme_leptin)))

Now, here’s where my confusion arises: I know a little about mediation analysis, where a mediator explains the mechanism or pathway through which X (independent variable) influences Y (the outcome). However, conceptually, mediation and interaction appear similar to me. For instance, in an interaction, we test whether the relationship between X1 and Y depends on
X2.Statistically, I understand these two analyses are different, but I’m unsure when to apply mediation versus interaction analysis.
Adding to the complexity, my study involves repeated measurements, and I’m not sure whether mediation is even applicable in this context. That’s probably a separate issue, but I’d greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on these points.
Thank you so much for your help!

The choice has to do with the assumed underlying causal chain.
Say that your question is whether to treat M as a mediator or a moderator of the association between X and Y. If X has no direct causal effect on M but the association between X and Y depends on the level of M, then M is a moderator that is modeled with an interaction (product) term X*M between the two predictor variables.
If you instead have reason to believe that X has a direct causal effect on M, with M then having a direct causal effect on Y, then M would be considered a mediator. In the simple mediation model shown by Shawn Hemelstrand on this page, analysis proceeds via regression of M as an outcome with predictor X and of Y as an outcome with predictor M.
The linear association between X and M, together with the subsequent linear association between M and Y, still leads to a linear association between X and Y through that mediation path. If you work through the equations for the mediation, you will see that (in this simple example) there is no interaction term X*M in the resulting set of equations. That makes this mediation model different from a moderation model, which necessarily includes an interaction term X*M.
Mediation analysis certainly can be appropriate with longitudinal studies. Longitudinal studies can document temporal associations that would be associated with the hypothesized causal chain.
How to proceed depends both on your understanding of the subject matter and how you intend to use the model. Including a mediator M as a predictor along with predictor X in a simple regression model for outcome Y runs the risk of understating the total association between X and Y. That might not pose a problem for predicting Y values from X and M values, however.
In your specific model, it seems that the primary interest is in the association between the (randomized) clinical trial group and leptin levels. With the randomization and that primary interest, there's no need to evaluate mediation. One might argue that no regression model at all is needed to evaluate that association, provided that randomization led to adequate balance of covariates among groups.
If you do perform a regression analysis for the randomized trial data, you should not include any potential mediators as predictors in the model lest that lead to an underestimation of the overall association between trial group and leptin, as noted above. I note that only initial weight is included in your model, not the weight over time that might be mediating any change in leptin. That's wise.
It might be possible to evaluate the underlying causal chain with mediation analysis. The clinical trial group can have no causal effect on any of the pre-intervention variables, so those certainly shouldn't be evaluated as mediators. You could use mediation analysis to evaluate whether treatment-associated weight changes might be responsible in part for changes in leptin levels.
Whatever the causal mechanism, however, your randomized trial will still document the overall association between clinical trial group and leptin.

I pretty understand the way you pose it but it's looks like a semantic game "If X has no direct causal effect on M but the association between X and Y depends on the level of M: moderator". It's not possible that they are not related, if the values are dependant on M. In this case it as you said "treatment-associated weight changes might be responsible in part for changes in leptin levels". In fact leptin levels and weight are related, fat mass is responsible for leptin synthesis, but how this relationship should be treated as interaction or mediation is something to discuss.

The balance of the trial, IMHO, has nothing to do here, with the mediation analysis. Randomization helps to prevent potential cofounding but no mediation is dealt, in fact, mediation effects could underly, and maybe we're not aware. Mediation analysis certainly can be appropriate with longitudinal studies. "Longitudinal studies can document temporal associations that would be associated with the hypothesized causal chain" - The thing is knowing that time may affect outcomes and predictors, how would you include a mediation that can be modulated across time.

@JavierHernando it's possible to have both moderation and mediation. As I understand your specific model, however, only initial weight peso1 is included as a predictor. That initial weight can't be in a causal chain between treatment group and leptin. For evaluating weight as a mediator, you would have to examine treatment-associated changes in weight. I understand that the R lavaan package can handle such complicated models, but I'm not an expert with it. Detailed consultation with a statistician experienced in causal analysis would be wise.
